# Disabling Windows Alt-Codes in PDCurses

Tags: c++, user-input, ncurses, alt, pdcurses

I was using PDCurses, and noticed that the library specifically defines the Alt-Numpad buttons. When implementing these buttons, however, I found that while using `getch()`, once you release the Alt-key it inputs the Alt-code you entered. Is there any way to disable this or use some sort of workaround?